# systemd: "apport-autoreport.path: Failed with result 'unit-start-limit-hit'" -> apport-autoreport.service fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, raspberry-pi, arm

The top Google result for this error is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267010/systemd1-apport-autoreport-service-failed-with-result-start-limit-hit), but it's from 1 year ago and doesn't work for me. I suspect this may end up as a bug report, but my systemd knowledge is minimal, so I'm asking here first.

### Problem

`apport-autoreport.path` fails, causing `apport-autoreport.service` to fail. (I understand that disabling apport is an option, but I would prefer to keep it enabled.)

### System

Raspberry Pi 4, Ubuntu 21.04 Raspberry Pi edition, arm64. Several desktop environments installed (MATE, lubuntu, cinnamon).
It's not exactly a "new clean install": I followed [an outdated tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Optional_PPAs) and installed some packages from PPAs (ubuntu-raspi2 and ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers). This caused an apt conflict, so I purged and removed them, which resolved the apt conflict. I have no reason to think that they did (or did not) cause this apport problem.

### Symptoms

This is the list of logs generated when apport-autoreport.service attempts to start: following reboot, or when I restart it, or after running `sudo apt reinstall -f apport`. (Screenshot from Cockpit):

**apport-autoreport.service:**

> [image: apport-autoreport.service logs]

---

**apport-autoreport.path:**

> [image: apport-autoreport.path logs]

I can include any of the listed logs upon request. To my untrained eye, I didn't find any useful information in them (they contain e.g. timestamps, machine_id, and so on).

### Attempted fix

When I attempt [the aforementioned fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267010/systemd1-apport-autoreport-service-failed-with-result-start-limit-hit), `apport-autoreport.path` gives the following two logs:

> [image]

The log title "Unknown key name 'PathChangedGlob' in section 'Path', ignoring" indicates that this fix does not work.

However: when `apport-autoreport.path` fails thus, `apport-autoreport.service` is able to start successfully. ("apport-autoreport.service: Succeeded.") Does this mean it's actually working? Or would it encounter an error if it actually tried to autoreport anything? It doesn't feel satisfactory, as systemd still registers as "degraded."

### What if I reinstall apport?

```
$ `sudo apt reinstall -f apport`
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute-updates/main arm64 apport all 2.20.11-0ubuntu65.1 [129 kB]
Fetched 129 kB in 1s (190 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 539076 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu65.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu65.1) over (2.20.11-0ubuntu65.1) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu65.1) ...
apport-autoreport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

This then returns to the same situation as seen in the "Symptoms" section above.

I'm happy to provide further info. I'm trying to do this properly, so that if this is a bug, we can find and report it. (And if so: where should I report it?)